# Looking for some sample code audio conversion with the iPhone caf=>m4a

Tags: iphone, audio, format

I am struggling with converting a recorded pcm/caf file (recorded via the AudioQueue) to a m4a file. I should be possible somehow with the "AudioConverter.h" but doesn't seem to be easy at all.

If you have seen an example or have a code snippet it would be great if you can post it.

Thanks for your help

Tom

Answer (score 5):

Here a code snippet from what I use in real live production code for converting audio files:

```
- (BOOL)convertWithDocument:(SoundDocumentCore*)document selection: (SoundSelection*)selection saveTo:(NSString*)path fileType:(UInt32)fileType progress:(ProgressSheet*)progress 
{
    OSStatus        err;
    ExtAudioFileRef eafRef;
    UInt32          n;
    UInt32          dataFormat = [self dataFormat];
    SInt32          bitRate = [self bitRate];

    // -- Data Source --
    // Calculate offsets from selection, if any
    UInt64      offset = 0,         length = [document numFrames];
    SInt32      trackOffset = 0,    numTracks = [document numTracks];
    if (selection != nil) {
        trackOffset = [selection firstTrack];
        numTracks  = [selection numTracks];
        offset = round ([selection startTime] * [document sampleRate]);
        length = round ([selection duration] * [document sampleRate]);
    }

    // -- Extended Audio File --
    NSString        *parentPath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    NSString        *fileName = [self flipColonsAndSlashes:[path lastPathComponent]];
    FSRef           parentDir;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription inputFormat, outputFormat;

    // Create FSRef from path
    err = FSPathMakeRef ((const UInt8*)[parentPath fileSystemRepresentation], &parentDir, nil);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] FSPathMakeRef() error %d", err); return NO;}

    // Delete the existing file
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeFileAtPath: path handler:nil];

    // Set up the input and output data formats
    inputFormat.mSampleRate = [document sampleRate];
    inputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    inputFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
    inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame   = sizeof(float) * numTracks;
    inputFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    inputFormat.mBytesPerPacket = inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame * inputFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
    inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = numTracks;
    inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 32;
    inputFormat.mReserved = 0;
    [self getFileDataFormat: &outputFormat];

    // Create an audio file and then wrap it with ExtAudioFile
    AudioFileID audioFileID;
    FSRef audioFileRef;
    err = AudioFileCreate(&parentDir, (CFStringRef) fileName, fileType, &outputFormat, nil, &audioFileRef, &audioFileID);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] AudioFileCreate() error %d", err); return NO;}

    // Add user data
    [self addUserDataToAudioFile:audioFileID];

    // Wrap it in ExtAudioFile
    err = ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID(audioFileID, YES, &eafRef);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID() error %d", err); return NO;}

    //err = ExtAudioFileCreateNew (&parentDir, (CFStringRef) fileName, fileType, &outputFormat, nil, &eafRef);
    //if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileCreateNew() error %d", err); return NO;}

    // Set the client data format
    err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty (eafRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof (AudioStreamBasicDescription), &inputFormat);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileSetProperty() error %d", err); return NO;}


    // -- AudioConverter Setup --
    AudioConverterRef       converter;
    n = sizeof (converter);
    err = ExtAudioFileGetProperty (eafRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_AudioConverter, &n, &converter);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileGetProperty() error %d", err); return NO;}

    // Set quality
    UInt32  quality = kAudioCodecQuality_Max;
    err = AudioConverterSetProperty(converter, kAudioConverterEncodeBitRate, sizeof (quality), &quality);

    // Set bit rate
    if ((bitRate != 0) && (dataFormat == kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)) {
        err = AudioConverterSetProperty(converter, kAudioConverterEncodeBitRate, sizeof (bitRate), &bitRate);
        if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] AudioConverterSetProperty() error %d", err);}
    }

    // Resynchronize ExtAudioFile with AudioConverter
    n = 0;
    err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty (eafRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ConverterConfig, sizeof (n), &n);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileSetProperty() error %d", err);}

    // -- Write Data --
    const UInt32        maxBufferSize   = 256 * 1024L;
    SInt64              remain = length;
    UInt32              frameSize       = inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
    UInt32              maxNumFrames    = maxBufferSize / frameSize;
    NSMutableData       *bufferListData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: 16];
    AudioBufferList     *bufferList     = [bufferListData mutableBytes];
    NSData              *bufferData;
    NSAutoreleasePool   *pool;
    BOOL                success = YES;

    // Loop
    while ((remain > 0) && (success == YES)) {
        pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        // Calculate number of frames to write
        n = (remain < maxNumFrames)? remain : maxNumFrames;

        // Get sample data from document
        bufferData = [document interleavedDataAtOffset: offset numFrames: n firstTrack: trackOffset numTracks: numTracks];

        // Set up audio buffer list
        bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
        bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = numTracks;
        bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = [bufferData length];
        bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = (void*) [bufferData bytes];

        // Write data to disk
        err = ExtAudioFileWrite (eafRef, n, bufferList);
        if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileWrite() error %d", err);}

        [pool release];

        // Update counters
        offset += n;
        remain -= n;

        // Update progress window
        [progress setMarkValue: [progress markValue] + n];
        if ([progress isCancelled]) success = NO;
    }

    // -- Clean Up --
    err = ExtAudioFileDispose (eafRef);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] ExtAudioFileDispose() error %d", err);}

    err = AudioFileClose (audioFileID);
    if (err != noErr) {if (mVerbose) NSLog(@"-[AudioFile convertWithDocument:] AudioFileClose() error %d", err);}

    return success;
}
```

Comment: From where i can get the library with few classes like SoundDocumentCore ?

Comment: That's a custom class which is a subclass of NSDocument. The purpose of this code is so you can learn how it works, and not for people to just copy and paste without knowing what they're doing.

Comment: Taken from Roger The Engineer's answer: You're setting *quality* and *bitrate* using the same property value of `kAudioConverterEncodeBitRate`. This is incorrect as codec quality is set using `kAudioConverterCodecQuality`. You wouldn't notice if this returned an error because you're not checking it, then you overwrite the `err` value.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting "quality" and "bitrate" using the same property value of kAudioConverterEncodeBitRate -- this is incorrect as codec quality is set using kAudioConverterCodecQuality. You wouldn't notice if this returned an error because you're not checking it, then you overwrite the err value.

I suggest looking at the ConvertFile Apple sample which demonstrates how to do this correctly and takes care of layered AAC formats and priming info.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ConvertFile/

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a thread-based forum. It is Q&A-focused. That means if you want to comment on an anser, you have to do so in a comment, not in a separate answer. Parts of your answer are a comment on a previous answer, so it should go into a comment. Because you were last seen on SO 3 years ago, I will copy your answer into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is sample code included with the free DiracLE time stretching library at http://dirac.dspdimension.com. I use their EAFWrite class in my code all the time because it wraps the whole AudioFile/ExtAudioFile API business nicely.